# how to set value in dropdown in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

could you please tell me how to set value in dropdown in react js ?
I am getting dropdown data after few seconds 3000 and then I need to set value on dropdown

```
const App = ({ children }) => {
  const val = "ax";
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setState(countryOptions);
  }, 2000);
  return (
    <Container style={{ margin: 20 }}>
      <Example countryOptions={state} />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-utev4
**expected output**
**Aland Islands** should be selected.
{ key: "ax", value: "ax", text: "Aland Islands" },

as after three second I want to select this element

```
const val = "ax";
```

Comment: Updated my answer, due to Stavros answer. It's better to keep what value is selected by default in the App component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stavros answer suggested; it may be better to keep state in App component and pass the setVal to the dropdown:

App:

```
const App = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  //added val and setVal in App state
  const [val,setVal]=useState('ax');
  setTimeout(() => {
    setState(countryOptions);
  }, 2000);
  return (
    <Container style={{ margin: 20 }}>
      //pass val and setVal so dropdown can set val on change
      <Example countryOptions={state} val={val} onChange={setVal}/>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Dropdown:

```
const DropdownExampleClearableMultiple = ({ countryOptions,val,onChange }) => (
  <Dropdown
    clearable
    fluid
    search
    closeOnChange
    selection
    options={countryOptions}
    //set value to passed in val
    value={val}
    //use setVal that was passed in as onChange
    onChange={(_,i)=>onChange(i.value)}
    placeholder="Select Country"
  />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should update your question because only after visiting the codesandbox was I able to get enough info for an answer..

In your index.js you should update setState(countryOptions) to :

```
setState({countryOptions:countryOptions},()=>setState({val:"ax"})
```

Then line 39  to :

```
<Example countryOptions={state.countryOptions:countryOptions} val={state.val} />
```

Then in your example.js update const DropdownExampleClearableMultiple to:

```
const DropdownExampleClearableMultiple = ({ countryOptions, val }) => (
<Dropdown
  clearable
  fluid
  search
  closeOnChange
  selection
  options={countryOptions}
  placeholder="Select Country"
  value={val}
/>
);
```

Comment: Good answer but OP uses hooks. So OP should create a hook for value `const [val, setVal] = useState();` and pass val to the component `val={val}` Also the user cannot change the input unless you pass onChange with value of setVal: `onChange={setVal}`

Comment: You are right. OP should update the dropdown and make it controlled but my understanding is that he/she doesn't have a good understanding of what he/she is doing here so I tried not to add more confusion.

Comment: I updated my answer, it would be better to keep state in App component and pass onChange from App

Answer (score 0):

Use the "value" prop.

```
// index.js
const App = ({ children }) => {
  const val = "ax";
  const [state, setState] = useState([]);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setState(countryOptions);
  }, 2000);
  return (
    <Container style={{ margin: 20 }}>
      <Example countryOptions={state} value={val} />
    </Container>
  );
};

// example.js
const DropdownExampleClearableMultiple = ({ countryOptions, value }) => (
  <Dropdown
    clearable
    fluid
    search
    closeOnChange
    selection
    value={value}
    options={countryOptions}
    placeholder="Select Country"
  />
);
```

Comment: Now the user cannot change the value of the dropdown as you never update val on change.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value to value property of Dropdown. Use state property for selected value.
Make sure that you change/update state on onchange event.