# why field is not clearable on click of cross button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

could you please tell me why the field is not clearable on click of a cross button?

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-torvalds-lhe9d
and value is not set to `final-form` why ?

```
 <RFField
              component={SingleSelectAutoComplete}
              label=""
              name="ag"
              placeholder=""
              required={true}
              val={value}
              data={state}
            />
```

I am facing two issues `values` is not clear when the cross button is clicked. secondly value is set in form.why ?

final form
https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/pull/209#issuecomment-377490998)

Comment: how to resolve this

Comment: please share the code sandbox

Comment: in sanbox there is as code `const [value, setValue] = useState("ax");` if you remove the `ax` from this then cross button is working

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as your misunderstanding [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57631368/103690). You need to let React Final Form manage your `value` prop for you.